# How to use VIRL Connect Tool

Tags: cisco, lab

I have just installed VIRL 1.6 today. I am a first time user.
Can someone please tell me how to have granular control over the connect tool.
I am trying to create a simple lab and when I try to create a connection between 2 devices, VIRL automatically chooses which port to connect on each device.

This becomes messy as I end up with discontiguous ports.

Eg:
[image]

Whereas, I am more used to creating labs with contiguous ports that are neat and more intuitive to work with as per below.

[image]

Thanks in advance. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to google a solution.

https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/102933

In VM Maestro -> Preferences -> Topology Editor -> uncheck the "Associate new connections with interfaces silently" check box -> Apply.

It will bring up a drop down interface list when using the Connect tool.